# Как сделать чтобы по нажатию кнопки менялся её размер или размер любой другой кнопки в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет! Задаю вопрос потому-что ответа нет нигде, я перерыл все сайты по этой теме нигде ничего нет. Пробывал найти решение сам путём подборки разных логичных слов в коде (size, deltasize, widht, heigth, vector и тд. тп.) но ничего не нашёл ):

Comment: А слово scale не очень логичное?

Comment: логичное но оно тоже не подходит лол

Comment: Так может ты код свой покажешь? Как оно не подходит.

Comment: [serializeField] private Button btn1;

Comment: btn1. и надо чтобы она двигалась меняла позицию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаешь пустышку на нее вешаешь скрипт:

```
[SerializeField] GameObject button;//сама кнопка
[SerializeField] Vector3 buttonScale;//до какого размера меняется кнопка
[SerializeField] float speed;//скорость перемещения кнопки
[SerializeField] Vector3 DirectionToMove;//направление перемещения кнопки

public void Buttontransform()
{
    button.transform.localScale = buttonScale;
    button.transform.Translate(DirectionToMove * speed);
}
```

в OnClick() перекидываешь эту пустышку и выбираешь функцию Buttontransform()